# How to upload image to PHP web server?

Tags: php, mysql

The following code upload a data to MySQL but I want add a browse button to upload image in MySQL.

How can I achieve this?

```
<form action='submiturl.php' method='POST'>
           <font face='sans-serif' size='5'>
           <center>
                   <span class="style2">Please fill out all fields to submit your Keyword.</span><br>
                   <br>
                   <span class="style2">Word Name:</span><br>
            <input type='text' size='50' name='title'><br><br> 
            <span class="style2">Keywords:</span><br><input type='text' size='50' name='keywords'><br>
            <span class="style2"><br>
Description</span><br><input name='description' type='text' value="" size='50' maxlength='200'>
<br><br>
             <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit URL'>
</form>
<br><a href='index.php' class="style2">Go Back</a></HTML>

<?php
// Language file in UTF-8
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$description = $_POST['description'];



$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","123_search","password");
mysql_select_db("123_search");

if (!$title||!$keywords||!$description)
{
  die ("<center>Please fill in all fields.</center>");
}
else
if ($submit)
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO searchengine VALUES('','$title','$keywords','$description')");
echo "<center>KeyWord Submitted!</center>";
}
else
echo "<center>Please fill in all fields.</center>";
?>
```

Comment: I will vote to close this old question as "needs focus" as it is too broad to answer.

Comment: Readers of this old question should be aware that it has serious SQL injection security vulnerabilities - **do not copy this code**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type='file' name='uploadimage'>`. It will create textbox with Browse button.

To learn more about how to store image in MySQL you can visit [this](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/40286-tutorial-storing-images-in-mysql-with-php/#axzz2DDFKerHp) link

Comment: I have added one link which will guide you to store image in mysql.Please refer my edited answer

Comment: Basically you have to create a field in a table of type `LONGBLOB` and dump the image binary in it, after escaping it with `mysql_real_escape_string` of course.

Answer (score -1):

Browse button to upload image in MySQL?

If you mean upload the image file to the remote directory (say, 'images/') but at the same time save the file-name in the table (mysql), then there are lots of tutorials that you can go through.

[Here](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/Upload_file_sql.htm) is the link.

A simple tutorial to upload the image and save the filename to a database.

### Edit

Add this in your form

```
<form action='submiturl.php' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Add a file button in your form

```
<input type="file" name="photo"><br>
```

Save the uploaded file in a directory

```
 $target = "images/"; //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
```

You can get the posted file information with all other posted data in your php with:

```
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); // this gets the filename of the upload pic
```

Now you can save this to your database table. Create a field in your db table for filename, and insert the filename with the rest as you have done in the question.

Comment: yes you are right upload the image in to remote dir but in this script how can i edit the upload code

Comment: thn u can go through the link(tutorial) that i provided..:)

Comment: your code is working but image is not upload in to a directory

Comment: wat path did u give.. i think ur path to the directory was not proper(correct).. give the rootpath to the directory... and let me know....